# How do I change the currency at "paypal page" from USD to AUD?

Tags: paypal, currency

All my buyers are using Australian currency and paypal shows USD to them when they are about to make payment,

I want to change this. How do I change the currency at "paypal page" from USD to AUD?

Comment: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/How-to-change-Paypal-default-currency-to-USD/td-p/616528

Comment: This question is off-topic and might belong on [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a currency code into whatever method you're using to integrate PayPal.

If you're using Payments Standard then you would add the following to your button or form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" />
```

If you're working with the APIs then the parameter is CURRENCYCODE and the value would be the same.